# All routes departing from a stop

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query in which my goal is to show routes departing from particular stop:

```
SELECT stops.stop_id, 
stops.stop_name, 
stops.stop_lat, 
stops.stop_lon, 
stops.zone_id, 
GROUP_CONCAT( distinct rt.route_short_name) as routes
FROM routes rt, trips tr, stop_times st, stops
WHERE rt.route_id = tr.route_id
and tr.trip_id = st.trip_id
and st.stop_id = stops.stop_id
and st.stop_id = 514
```

I would like to achieve the same for my search query which is kind of simple for now:

```
SELECT stop_id, stop_name, stop_lat, stop_lon, zone_id FROM stops WHERE stop_name LIKE '%$search_term%'
```

How to show in my search result stop names with routes associated with each stop?

Comment: What's your DB? If you want "stop XYZ, route 1;route 2; route 3" it can't be done in an agnostic way (for example in T-SQL you may use STUFF function).

Comment: I'm using MySQL. The result from query for single stop defined by id is fine. I have another field with all routes separated with coma and that is fine for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merge the two where clauses by replacing `st.stop_id = 512` with `stop.stop_name LIKE '%search%'`.

You'll also need the `GROUP BY` clause because your original query was implicitly grouping.

```
SELECT
    stops.stop_id, 
    stops.stop_name, 
    stops.stop_lat, 
    stops.stop_lon, 
    stops.zone_id, 
GROUP_CONCAT( distinct rt.route_short_name) as routes
FROM routes rt, trips tr, stop_times st, stops
WHERE rt.route_id = tr.route_id
and tr.trip_id = st.trip_id
and st.stop_id = stops.stop_id
and stops.stop_name LIKE '%$search_term%'
GROUP BY
    stops.stop_id, 
    stops.stop_name, 
    stops.stop_lat, 
    stops.stop_lon, 
    stops.zone_id
```

Comment: I've started with that and it's not working. That's why I've posted my question. Thanks though!

Comment: It will give me just one result with messed routes (plenty of them)

Comment: @dargod - Try it again now.  I've added a GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Perfect! It takes a while (3sec) but that is what I needed :)